# Custom Event for Wordpress Cron Job Not executing

Tags: php, wordpress

Method to Execute at Certain Interval

```
function informant_main_action(){
    die('working');
}
```

Custom Schedule for Cron Job

```
    function my_cron_definer($schedules){  
        $schedules['weekly'] = array('interval'=> 120, //604800
            'display'=>  __('Once Every week')  
            );  
        return $schedules;
    }
    add_filter('cron_schedules','my_cron_definer');
```

Register schedule on plugin activation

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'informant_run_on_activation' );

function informant_run_on_activation(){
    if(!wp_next_scheduled('informantweeklynewsletter')){
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'weekly', 'informantweeklynewsletter');
    }
}
```

Calling my method to be executed on custom event

```
add_action('informantweeklynewsletter','informant_main_action');
```

I have installed a plugin Cron Gui for viewing scheduled cronjob and it is listing my event correctly as i put the recurrence for every two minutes the cron gui shows the correct result i.e its updating the time +2 minutes.

But my method `informant_main_action()` is not working. Whats the mistake i am making. ?

Thanks

Comment: Try a mail function instead of die....you can never be sure if you will be one to trigger the cron....

Answer (score 0):

To test cron use something like mail().....try hourly to test and then your weekly one. Its a good idea to destroy the event on plugin de-activation (there is also a theme de-activation hook, look it up if you need it) so you can de-activate the plugin if you need to make changes without changing the hook name.

```
add_action('test_event', 'informant_main_action');

function informant_main_action() {
    mail('youremailaddress', 'cron running', 'your cronjob has completed');
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'informant_run_on_activation' );

function informant_run_on_activation() {
   if(!wp_next_scheduled('test_event')){
      wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'test_event');
   }
}

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'deactivate_cron' );

function deactivate_cron() {
   wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'monday_event' );
}
```